# Regex help needed: pattern almost works

Tags: javascript, regex

I am needing a bit of help with regular expressions for ECMAScript. The regex I am currently using almost works as desired, but there is a small hiccup. I need to match the following:

`STAT` or `STATS` regardless of case. Additionally, there may be symbols and numbers that follow.

Example:
`stats:3-2` is a match.
`stats:5` is a match.
`stats-4` is a partial match, but the '-4' should be ignored.

The current regex I am using, as already noted, almost works and is as follows:
`/STAT[S]*(?:(?:[\:](?<method>(\d)))(?:[\-](?<count>(\d)+))*)*/ig`

This pattern, using regex101, actually matches all conditions and ignores the -4 in the following example: `stats-4`, while matching the word 'stats'.

However, when I attempt to use this pattern in a plugin that I am editing, problems arise. It currently only matches `stat`, `stats`, `stat:2`, but not `stat:3-2`, `stat-4` (which should match the 'stat' but ignore the '-4').

I am aware the pattern may be a bit messy, but I am not good with creating regular expressions.

Exact usage (in atom rpg-dice plugin):

```
    roll() {
        const editor = atom.workspace.getActiveTextEditor();
        const regex = [
            /(\+|\-){1}([\d]+)/i,
            /([\d]+)d([\d]+)(?:([\+|\-]){1}([\d]+))*/i,
            /STAT[S]*(?:(?:[\:](?<method>(\d)))?(?:[\-](?<count>(\d)+))*)*/i
        ];

        if (editor) {
            // attempt to select the dice roll
            let selection = editor.getSelectedText();
            // if the selection failed, try selection another way.
            if (selection.length < 1) {
                editor.selectWordsContainingCursors();
                atom.commands.dispatch(atom.views.getView(editor), 'bracket-matcher:select-inside-brackets');
                selection = editor.getSelectedText();
            }
            // increase size of selection by 1, both left and right. (selects brackets)
            let range = editor.getSelectedBufferRange();
            let startColumn = range.start.column -1;
            let endColumn = range.end.column +1;
            editor.setSelectedBufferRange([[range.start.row, startColumn],[range.end.row, endColumn]]);
            // trim any whitespace from the selection
            selection.trim();

            /*
                regex pattern matching to determine the
                type of roll.
             */
             if (matches = selection.match(regex[0])) {                          // 1d20 roll; attack and ability checks
                type = 'check';
             } else if (matches = selection.match(regex[1])) {                   // typically a damage dice roll
                type = 'dmg';
             } else if (matches = selection.match(regex[2])) {                   // used for stat generation
                console.log(matches);
             } else {
                console.log('Cannot determine a suitable use.');
             }
```

Comment: `/STATS?(?::(?<method>\d)(?:-(?<count>\d+))?)?/gi` [should work](https://regex101.com/r/o4NDVT/1) if the plugin supports the latest ECMAScript specs.

Comment: I just tried that, and it still isn't working.  Basically, if I add - followed by a digit, it doesn't work.

Comment: @JLDNAdmin because your first `\d` isn't preceded by the optional `-` like the second one is.

Comment: @r3wt can you show me? I am not following.

Comment: try this: `/STAT[S]*(?:(?:[\:](?<method>(\d)))?(?:[\-](?<count>(\d)+))*)*/ig`

Comment: `/STAT[S]*(?:(?:[\:](?:[-]?\d)|(?<method>(\d)))?(?:[\-](?<count>(\d)+))*)*/ig` i can't test it but i believe this should make the `-4` non capturing for `stats-4` example you gave. all tests cases you list pass but i can't see the capturing groups on regexr.com here is my work space https://regexr.com/5kg4c

Comment: I do not think it works, @r3wt, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/XXrXaq/1), as it grabs a number after `-`.

Comment: so far, it is not working. I can't understand why it fails if the string contains a  - followed by a number.

Comment: when i use your original regular expression it works. can you tell us what plugin you are using so we can attempt reproduce the issue?

Comment: I am modifying a dice roller plugin for atom. The plugin is called rpg-dice and can be found on GitHub. I am modifying it for additional functionality, so what I have in my current copy of the source can not be found in the original plugin. Give me a moment and I can edit my post to show exactly how it is used.

Comment: @JLDNAdmin As usual with dashes, are they really hyphens? Try `/STATS?(?::(?<method>\d)(?:[-–—](?<count>\d+))?)?/gi`

Comment: question updated with the code in which the regex is being used in.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have just went back and to do some code clean up and suddenly, your regex is working as expected. Thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
/STATS?(?::(?<method>\d)(?:-(?<count>\d+))?)?/gi
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/o4NDVT/1). *Details*:

- `STATS?` - `STATS` or `STAT`
- `(?::(?<method>\d)(?:-(?<count>\d+))?)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `:` - a colon
  - `(?<method>\d)` - Group "method": a single digit
  - `(?:-(?<count>\d+))?` - an optional occurrence of

    - `-` - a hyphen
    - `(?<count>\d+)` - Group "count": one or more digits.